# Why Can't I Pass a String?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a quiz program to work in PHP. Up until now, I've had little problem getting any code I write to work. However, this time, I can't seem to get a string to pass to the next page of a form. The basic idea is a trivia program. A random question is retrieved, the user answers the question, the program checks to see if the answer is right. Eventually, the program will keep score, but I haven't got that far yet because I can't seem to check the answer against the question. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

If there's an answer to this, I'm sorry, I missed it. The only thing I saw said to use Javascript, which is beyond my current skillset.  Thanks.

The Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
<!--link-->
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Sports Trivia</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<?php>
     extract($_REQUEST);
     include("triviaQuestions.php");

     //functions
     //Display Next Question template provided by Dan Brekke
     function nextQuestion($trivia,&$used)
     {
          do
               $num = rand(0,count($trivia)-1);
          while ($used[$num]);
          $used[$num] = true;
          reset($trivia);
          for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
               next($trivia);
          return key($trivia);
     }

     function displayQuestion($trivia,$count,&$used,$question)
     {
          if ($count < count($trivia))
          {
               $questionNum = $count+1;

               echo <<< HERE
               <h3>Question $questionNum:</h3>
               <h3>$question</h3>
HERE;
          }
          else
               $question = "You've reached the endzone!";
     }

     function displayButtons()
     {
          echo <<< HERE
          <p>
          <input type="submit" name="button" value="Next Question" />
          <input type="submit" name="button" value="Quit" />
          </p>
HERE;
     }

     function passData($trivia,$count,$used)
     {
          echo "<input type='hidden' name='count' value='$count'>";
          for ($i = 0; $i < count($trivia); $i++)
               echo "<input type='hidden' name='used[$i]' value='$used[$i]'>";
     }

     if ($button == NULL || $button == "New Game")
     {
          //variables
          $used = NULL;
          $count = 0;
          $correct = 0; 

          echo <<< HERE
          <h1>Sports Trivia!</h1>
          <h3>Welcome to Sports Trivia. Enter your name and click Play to begin!</h3>
          <h3>Name:
          <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" autofocus="on">
          </h3>
          <input type="submit" name="button" value="Play" />
          <input type="submit" name="button" value="Display Scores" />
          <br /><br />
          <a href="..">Back To Home</a>
HERE;
          //experimenting, since I don't know how this works
          serialize($trivia);
          serialize($used);
     }
     else
     {
          if ($button == "Play")
          {
               $question = nextQuestion($trivia,$used);
               displayQuestion($trivia,$count,$used,$question);
               echo <<< HERE
               <input type="text" name="answer" autocomplete="off" autofocus="on" />
               <p>
               <input type="submit" name="button" value="Enter" />
               </p>
HERE;
          }

          else if ($button == "Enter")
          {
               echo $question;
          }
     }
     echo <<< HERE
     <input type="hidden" name=$helloWorld />
HERE;
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right now, I'm just trying to get the $question to show on the page after I click "Enter". The best I've gotten so far is the first word of the question.

Comment: you could also try the session route

Comment: In addition to being a huge security hole, `extract($_REQUEST)` makes it very difficult to see what could be wrong with your code.

Comment: See, I read that as well. I am extremely interested in secure code, so I know it's a bad practice, but I can't seem to make $_GET or $_POST work for me. Likely a syntax issue, but I haven't explored it enough. I'd take suggestions there as well, but my main interest right now is getting the $question string to pass more than just the first word. $answer passes the entire string, so I don't understand how they are any different.

Comment: You have a typo in line 12. `<?php>` should be `<?php`. None of the PHP will execute if you don't have the correct opening tag, it will just be included as if it were HTML.